# how to work with SAP UI5 xml views

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAP UI5.

Here my task is to convert javascript code to xml view. Here javascript is like:

```
 var sHtmlText = '<strong>Aliquam erat volutpat.</strong><br>Vivamus vitae felis nec lacus ultricies dapibus condimentum quis felis.';
    sHtmlText += 'Some link goes here:<embed data-index=\"0\">';

    var oLink2 = new sap.ui.commons.Link("l2", {
        text : "Click me",
        href : "http://scn.sap.com/welcome",
        title : "SAP Community Network",
        target : "_blank"
    });

    var oFTV2 = new sap.ui.commons.FormattedTextView("otv2");
    //set the text with placeholders inside
    oFTV2.setHtmlText(sHtmlText);
    //add the desired control to the FormattedTextView
    oFTV2.addControl(oLink2);

    var oCallout = new sap.ui.commons.Callout({
        content : oFTV2
    });

    // create a sample form with two fields and assign a callout to each of them
    var oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({
        layoutFixed : false
    });
    var oTextField, oLabel;
    oLayout.createRow(
        oLabel = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"First name:", labelFor:"firstname1"}),
        oTextField = new sap.ui.commons.TextField("firstname1", {required:true, value:"John"})
    );
    oTextField.setTooltip(oCallout);
    // display it
    oLayout.placeAt("sample2");
```

While running the above code i am getting the text field with a label and input hover popup.

Now my task is to convert the above js view to XML View. I am getting confused.

Please suggest me the exact procedure (generalized manner) for converting the above JS view to XML view.

Answer (score 5):

A quick (and dirty) way is to simply run your application, and when in the view you want to convert to XML, open the SAPUI5 Diagnostics screen (`Ctrl-Alt-Shift S`), show the Control Tree panel, select the topmost UIArea element, click the 'Export' tab on the right and click the 'Export to XML' button :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add name space for your sap.ui.Commons xmlns:com="sap.ui.Commons" in your xml view 
then write code like this

for more reference please check [xml view developer guide](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/e3b5323649b44d9a883a6233fb01ee9d.html)

and example here [Example](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/e3b5323649b44d9a883a6233fb01ee9d.html)

click on Expample in Master side then select on Detail Side and do show code